# How can give group in active directory folder access by group policy

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, group-policy, file-permissions

I have windows server 2003 64bit and my clients running on windows xp 32bit.
My clients have user rights so they can't install any program.
I have some programs needs admin rights for example I have French dictionary without admin right the program will not work properly.
I don't want go to each PC and login with admin account then go to program folder located in programs files to give full permission to the group.
Is there a way to add them folder in group policy so I can force all the PCs to have full access on the folder?
Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Group Policy should handle this without problems. Example I have for locking down the C: root folder on Windows 7:

Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > File System > %SystemDrive%\

- Permissions

  - Type: Allow, Name: BUILTIN\Administrators, Permission: Full Control, Apply to: This folder, subfolders and files
  - Type: Allow, Name: CREATOR OWNER, Permission: Full Control, Apply to: Subfolders and files only
  - Type: Allow, Name: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM, Permission: Full Control, Apply to: This folder, subfolders and files
  - Type: Allow, Name: BUILTIN\Users, Permission: Read and Execute, Apply to: This folder, subfolders and files
- Allow inheritable permissions from the parent to propagate to this object and all child objects: Disabled

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A little hard to understand, but I think what you need is to create a user group for the users who would need access, then assign the appropriate NTFS permissions to that group in the folder.

Comment: what I have done is first I installed the program on active directory then I created new policy by editing: -
Computer setting à Computer setting à Security setting à file system
Added new file and specify where I installed the program (c:\program files\program name) then selected the group (who want to have full access) and I gave him full permission after another menu for configure this files or folder
I selected the option say replace existing permissions on all subfolders and files with inheritable permissions.
I forced the clients and I have restarted PCs but nothing work.Thanks alot

Comment: That covers NTFS permissions ... does the group also have rights to access the network share?

Comment: Should be yes because I have added registry keys and it's working! so what should I check more?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to allow a group of people admin rights within a specific folder to allow them to install the program themselves. If that is the case, then I believe you can add a group into your Active Directory such as **TEMP ADMIN** and add all of the users you want to have the privileges to that group. Then explore or log into your Domain Control, locate the folder and add the group **TEMP ADMIN** to the security tab under property settings. This should allow the users to access and install the folder contents.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply could you please read what I have wrote in previous comment.Sorry for bad explanation

Comment: O shoot sorry about that. Guess you were one step ahead of me already. Well I thought that would work but I'll look more into it.